# PHP Imagick PSD thumbs getting strange artifacts

Tags: php, imagick

We have a server that accepts PSD files. It will load it into a new Imagick object and create 4 **jpg** thumbs for it.

Oddly the first thumb, the largest one looks great. Each thumb after that experiences some image distortion where a layer was using a stroke effect.

Code:

```
$image = new Imagick($fileName);
$image->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

foreach ($thumbSizes as $key => $size) { //largest to smallest
     if($size>$longestSide){
          $size = $longestSide;
     }
     $this->image->thumbnailImage($size,$size,true);
     $this->image->writeImage($nameBase . '-' . $key . ".$extension");
}
$image->destroy();
```

I'm not sure how Imagick works internally, but my intuition tells me that if the largest thumb is accurate then each one after that should be.[image: Example Image]

**NOTE**: I expect some image distortion when resizing an image. But if you look at the example I posted it's different than your normal resizing artifacts. It's changing the color of some text. I assume it's a problem with it resizing the stroke effect. But I would have thought since I flattened the image first, the stroke effect wouldn't exist anymore. I can pass in a jpeg representation of the same file and it resizes them all perfectly.

Comment: Did the example image show up for you? It's changing the color on the image, look the the '01.' It's red then suddenly black. I totally expect image distortion with downsizing, not color changing.

Comment: @developerwjk if it starts as a JPG instead of a PSD it doesn't happen

Comment: @Sean256 can you provide an example psd? This is very likely to be an issue with the package that is actually doing the conversion - usually inkscape or rsvg.

Comment: I was thinking I was avoiding that by using mergeImageLayers

Comment: @developerwjk you are not being helpful.....the images are clearly different, and not consistent.

Comment: @Danack Here is the original file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdbp8ok9tv872q3/testImageVendor01.psd?dl=0

Comment: This is also not an answer - there's something weird with the PSD. Doing the convert directly with ImageMagick with "convert -composite vendor01.psd vendor.png" gives an image that has no color for the number. Opening the image with Photoshop elements, it seems there is some FX on the number - maybe whichever library is being used by ImageMagick to convert the PSD to a pixel image is getting confused. Can you remove the FX stuff from that element of the PSD?

Comment: @Danack Yeah I could remove the FX, but we can’t expect our internal users to do this. Since the thumbs look fine starting with a jpg and the first thumb is good, is there a way to change the format in memory to jpg before I start the thumb process? That way the thumbs are created from a jpg image and not PSD? I don’t like the idea of writing it out to a file and reloading it since we are storing them on a NAS. If I have to I could always load the first created thumb, which is fine, and make each one after that from it.

Comment: "Since the thumbs look fine starting with a jpg and the first thumb is good" I think it's only working by coincidence i.e. that the library doing the conversion is totally confused and that it's only by chance that it seems right.  The first image doesn't appear correct for me with the same code. btw as Imagick uses the ImageMagick library to do all the work, you can test with more quickly with the CLI version of "convert -composite vendor01.psd vendor.png". Until it's working in that, there's no chance of it working through Imagick.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PSD conversion is just borked by the library/special FX on the PSD. This is the first image output by similar code to yours:

[image]

The color of the number is transparent rather than black - but similarly, not correct. If the issue is being caused by the FX on that layer and you can't find a version of the library that processes the PSD that works correctly, I would suggest not using Imagick/ImageMagick to do the processing, but instead install a copy of Photoshop on the server and use the CLI processing capabilities of Photoshop itself to do the processing: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html .

btw an observation - you are resizing the same image repeatedly, this is less than optimal. You can avoid this by resizing a clone of the original image:

```
foreach ($thumbSizes as $key => $size) { //largest to smallest

    $temp = clone $image;
    if($size>$longestSide){
         $size = $longestSide;
    }
    $temp->thumbnailImage($size,$size,true);
    $temp->writeImage($nameBase . '-' . $key . ".$extension");
}
```

This should give a slightly higher output image quality.

Comment: That's actually how we had it to start. It was doing the same thing with the red-black color change. The final thumbs were a little better overall (less compression artifacts) but it took a few ms longer. To us the compression artifacts are worth the ms in time we save, however the red-black bug isn't.

Comment: It's funny, dropbox display the preview off too. They are probably using the same library.